# Deep learning model for more than 3000 classes, Image classification with CNN

Tags: python, classification, cnn, image

I want to create a CNN for image classification but I have more than 3000 classes in my dataset, is this possible in deep learning ? Can anyone help!

Comment: What type of help?

Comment: is it possible to build a CNN for more than 3000 labels? ( my dataset contains more than 3000 directories, each one contains images to be classified).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

For 3000 classes classification, we use a network with 3000 outputs and then apply a softmax function.

[here](https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/vgg16/) is the link to a VGG paper, a CNN used to perform 1000 classes classification.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. That's what I wanted to apply, I use the VGG network and then all I have to do is to add the FC layer with 3000 outputs, that's right?

Comment: Yup, if you wanna use transfer learning, then you should train the classifier part of VGG with a last FC layer with 3000 outputs and then use the softmax function to get the probabilities of each class.

Comment: Yes, I will test that and I hope to have good results because there are some classes that contain images that are a little bit similar. Thank you